# Set Multi-Valued Strings MS AD using Powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

How can I set a Multi-Valued Attribute in AD. For example I need to set msDS-AllowedDNSSuffixes on root domain object. If I do it through ADSIEdit it adds one value at a time.

I tried:

```
Set-ADObject -Identity 'b313bf35-f3ab-4074-8255-f38dc1217c06' -Replace @{'msDS-AllowedDNSSuffixes'='aaa.contoso.com; bbb.contoso.com'}
Set-ADObject -Identity 'b313bf35-f3ab-4074-8255-f38dc1217c06' -Replace @{'msDS-AllowedDNSSuffixes'='aaa.contoso.com\nbbb.contoso.com'}
Set-ADObject -Identity 'b313bf35-f3ab-4074-8255-f38dc1217c06' -Replace @{'msDS-AllowedDNSSuffixes'='aaa.contoso.com;bbb.contoso.com'}
```

It adds all as one line, shown in ADSIEdit.

also i tried:

```
$suffixes = @"
aaa.contoso.com
bbb.contoso.com
"@
foreach ($i in $suffixes) {
Set-ADObject -Identity 'b313bf35-f3ab-4074-8255-f38dc1217c06' -Add @{'msDS-AllowedDNSSuffixes'= $i}
}
```

The same thing.

How to set value of such type of attribute? What delimiter to use?

Comment: What happens if you try `Set-ADObject -Identity 'b313bf35-f3ab-4074-8255-f38dc1217c06' -Replace @{'msDS-AllowedDNSSuffixes'=@("aaa.contoso.com","bbb.contoso.com")}`?

Comment: Do you mind if I post that as an answer for you to accept?

Comment: Sure thing, buddy.

Answer (score 5):

Set the value to an array of the settings required; e.g.

```
Set-ADObject -Identity 'b313bf35-f3ab-4074-8255-f38dc1217c06' -Replace @{'msDS-AllowedDNSSuffixes'=@("aaa.contoso.com","bbb.contoso‌​.com")}
```